# Calatheas & allies as houseplants without climate control

Tags: houseplants, indoors, climate

I live in a warm Mediterranean climate. Close to the sea, summer is humid, but air may be dryer in winter possibly because the wind arrives from over the European continent during most of its time.

The location: inside the house. Temperature may be slightly above 15°c or 59°F in winter. Lighting issues are to be taken care of, but temperature and humidity are not controlled. We have heating, but this is rarely needed. Summer temperatures peak to around 30°c or 86°F. Cooling is used slightly more often, but then the A/C dries-up the air.

Would my Calatheas  Maranthas and Ctenanthas make it through the harsh days?

Answer (score -1):

I can't see why not.  As long as you do not have extended periods of cold below 10°c then you should be able to grow both of these plants with no problem.  Give them bright indirect or diffused light.  A good potting soil in a pot with holes in the bottom.  Water them when they need it, never letting the soil completely dry out.  Rain water is preferable. Reverse osmosis and distilled water would be second to rain water. Most tap water will work.  Some country water can be high in various minerals, depending on the source.  Some municipal water can be heavily treated with Chlorine or similar product. Some other filters can be adequate.  Water softener can be deadly.